# Proof that omitting insignificant features in Linear Regression does not change the result

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, feature-selection, regression-coefficients

I am trying to understand whether omitting insignificant features (with weights close to zero) will change the overall result of a multiple linear regression problem and if so by how much. In particular, I would be interested in deriving an ***explicit error bound*** (if this is possible at all?).

**1) To establish a common ground, here's my setup**

- $\min || y - \hat{y} ||_2^2$ with $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ ... \\ y_N \end{bmatrix}$ and $\hat{y}_i = w_0 + w_1x_1 + ... + w_M x_M$
- Means we have N samples of a setup with M feature variables
- In short, I write : $\min || y - Xw ||_2^2$ with $X = \begin{bmatrix} - x_{(1)} - \\ ... \\ - x_{(N)} - \end{bmatrix}$ being the NxM matrix of N observations of the respective M features
- The explicit solution via Least Squares is given by the pseudo-inverse : $w_{LS} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^{T}y = X^+ y$

**2) Now, intuition and performance metrics tell me that**

- If $w_i = 0$, then the corresponding feature $x_i$ is insignificant and can be dropped
- This is because including $x_i$ will not increase the fit, i.e. the sum of squares around the fit is not getting better (smaller)
- To determine which features might be insignificant, it makes sense to exclude highly correlated features beforehand. This can be done by recalling the assumption for linear regression that the target $y$ is being *normally distributed* with some variance $\sigma^2$. It can be shown that the variance for the weight vector $w_{LS}$ is $\sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$. Of course, we opt for low variance and this can be analyzed using a SVD of the feature matrix $X = USV^T$ as follows. The variance is given by $Var[w_{LS}] = \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1} = \sigma^2VS^{-2}V^T$. For highly correlated features, the values in $S$ will be small and thus the inverse will be very large due to the power of 2. We can use this analysis to determine correlated features and exclude them, consequently.
- Then, practically, we could compute the adjusted $R^2$ and $p$ values for the setup with and without the insignificant values and compare them.

This would be a purely pragmatic approach though with a little prior analysis.

**3) The real-world problem**

- In reality, we will most likely never have perfect $w_i = 0$
- From a purely theoretical point of view, can we use the LS solution to further derive an error bound on leaving out a feature per se?

I am thinking about something like this: We have that $w_{LS} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^{T}y = X^+ y$. Using the SVD for the pseudo-inverse, we could split this argument up again. Can we use the singular values in this exact scenario already to determine insignificant variables? And if we decide to omit say $x_i$, whether being it significant or insignificant, can we derive an error metric, say based on the R^2 ?

These are just some (maybe trivial) problems of a student :-) Any discussion is very much appreciated!

Thanks!